# How to draw a line dynamically between two circles

Tags: d3.js, svg

I have drawn two circles with the below code, i have to draw a line between these two circles but the tricky point when i start to draw a line from the first circle there should be availability of second circle then only it should draw otherwise it shouldn't draw line and vice versa. if i click outside of  circle then also  it shouldn't draw line

in my below code or fiddle check it i can a draw a line my condition is not working

```
   var line;

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg") 
    .attr("width", 600)
    .attr("height", 400).on("mousedown", mousedown).on("mouseup", mouseup);

function mousedown() {
    var m = d3.mouse(this);
    line = vis.append("line")
        .attr("x1", m[0])
        .attr("y1", m[1])
        .attr("x2", m[0])
        .attr("y2", m[1]);

    svg.on("mousemove", mousemove);
}

function mousemove() {
    var m = d3.mouse(this);
    line.attr("x2", m[0])
        .attr("y2", m[1]);
}

function mouseup() {
    svg.on("mousemove", null);
}

var inputs = [
{ "x" : 200, "y" : 150,  r : 50},
{ "x" : 300,  "y" : 250,  r : 50},
]

         svg.selectAll("circle").data(inputs).enter().append("circle")

         .attr("r", function(d, i){ return d.r })
         .attr("cx", function(d, i){ return d.x })
         .attr("cy", function(d, i){ return d.y })            
         .attr("stroke", "red")
         .attr("fill", "white")
```

Here is my fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/34j6pkn9/1/

Comment: mybe this will help https://bl.ocks.org/cjrd/6863459

Comment: No error but line is not drawing

Answer (score 1):

maybe this will help you but its far from a good solution, but it work

> Note : 
>   circle drawing its bit ridiculus for me, it draw rect, imagine you
>   draw rect first then you draw a circle inside of it that its why, it
>   have bug on each angle of it that look like circle but difinetly its
>   a reactangle,
>
> i think it can be solve by some calculation,but sorry i didnt know any of
>   that

```js
var line;
var mx =0
var my =0
var inputs = [
{ "x" : 200, "y" : 150,  r : 50},
{ "x" : 300,  "y" : 250,  r : 50},
]
var vis = d3.select("body").append("svg") 
    .attr("width", 600)
    .attr("height", 400)
    .on("mouseup", mouseup);


function mousedown() {
    var m = d3.mouse(this);

    line = vis.append("line")
        .attr("x1", m[0])
        .attr("y1", m[1])
        .attr("x2", m[0])
        .attr("y2", m[1]);
     mx = m[0]
     my = m[1]
    vis.on("mousemove", mousemove);
}

function mousemove() {
    var m = d3.mouse(this);
    line.attr("x2", m[0])
        .attr("y2", m[1]);
}

function mouseup() {
 var m = d3.mouse(this);
  //console.log(mx-m[0],my-m[1])
 inputs.forEach(function(d,i){
 if(m[0]<(d.x+d.r)&& m[0]>(d.x-d.r)&&m[1] <(d.y+d.r)&& m[1]>(d.y-d.r)){
  if(mx<(d.x+d.r)&& mx>(d.x-d.r)&&my <(d.y+d.r)&& my>(d.y-d.r)){
 
 }else{
  vis.on("mousemove", null);
 }
   
  }
 })
   
}



         vis.selectAll("circle").data(inputs).enter().append("circle")
         
         .attr("r", function(d, i){ return d.r })
         .attr("cx", function(d, i){ return d.x })
         .attr("cy", function(d, i){ return d.y })            
         .attr("stroke", "red")
         .attr("fill", "white")
         .on("mousedown", mousedown).on("mouseup", mouseup);
```

```css
svg {
    border: 1px solid red;
}

line {
    stroke: steelblue;
    stroke-width: 2px;
    stroke-linecap: round;
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/4.2.3/d3.min.js"></script>

  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head><body>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

There will be a *line* after every circle (except the first one). Each line will connect the centers of every two consecutive circles.

You've the *first circle* which you are appending in your *svg* now, but how will you find the *previous circle*? You can, simply, find [previousElementSibling](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_element_previouselementsibling.asp) of the *first circle*. But, there is catch here, notice there is line after every circle. So, be sure to check the name of the *previousElementSibling* if it's "line", find *previousElementSibling* once more.

```js
// At this point, you've just appended the circle in 
// 'svg' based on where the mouse is etc.

// Now, find the previous circle.
const parentNode = document.querySelector("svg");
// 'thisCircle' is the one you're appending in svg now.
const thisCircle = parentNode.lastElementChild;

// Previous sibling of this circle. 
const previousSibling = thisCircle.previousElementSibling;
// If this is the first circle drawn, then do nothing- return
if (!previousSibling) {
  return;
}

// Check if previous sibling is indeed 'circle' and not 'line'
const nodeNameOfPreviousSiblig = previousSibling.nodeName;
let previousCircle = previousSibling;
// If the previous node is 'line' go one more step upwards- it must be a circle. Since pattern => 1 circle, 1 line.
if (nodeNameOfPreviousSiblig == 'line') {
  previousCircle = previousSibling.previousElementSibling;
}

// center of the previous circle.
const xCoordOPrevCircleCenter = previousCircle.getAttribute("cx");
const yCoordOPrevCircleCenter = previousCircle.getAttribute("cy");
```

Now, finally, append the line connecting these two consecutive circles centers:

```js
svg.append('line')
  .attr('x1', xCoordOThisCircleCenter)
  .attr('y1', yCoordOThisCircleCenter)
  .attr('x2', xCoordOPrevCircleCenter)
  .attr('y2', yCoordOPrevCircleCenter)
```